# Is Visual Studio needed to deploy ASP .NET web app on MS IIS Server Express?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express

Can I deploy `ASP.NET` web application on `Microsoft IIS Server express` without `Visual Studio` i.e. by copying the contents of project folder to the default folder for web pages? 
My OS is `Windows 10`.
I tried but got an error below upon browsing at localhost:8080.

`"The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located."`

Comment: Yes, if everything needed is installed and everything required is  **deployed**.

Comment: I tried doing what I said above but I received an error on my web browser "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located."